# Infinite number of stationary distributions for Simple Random Walk with 2 absorbing barriers?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, random-walk, stationary-processes

Question:

For a simple random walk with two absorbing barriers at a and -b, show from first principles that there are an infinite number of stationary distributions which must satisfy
π<sub>a</sub> + π<sub>-b</sub> = 1 where π<sub>i</sub> denotes the stationary probability of the i-th state.

I have got up to the following but am unsure how to proceed:
[Working thus far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m1Ou.jpg)

Comment: You might be making this problem too hard.  Think about  the definition of "absorbing barrier."  What happens as time goes to infinity? What do you think a particular stationary distribution would be?

Comment: Hello @Michael, thanks for the response. Yes I understand that the absorbing barriers mean that the distribution will eventually end up at either end as n tends to infinity. I believe some stationary distributions look like:
 
π=[0.5 0.5]
or
π=[0.6 0.4]
or 
π=[0.4 0.6]

How then can I show the infinite number of these solutions? Thanks

Comment: If you have two solutions to a linear system of equations, then any mixture of them is also a solution.